# Prioritizing a pipe/alternative in a regex pattern

Tags: regex

I am scanning a text block and trying to get a `Capture Group` I'm calling `Value`. The problem  it can either be in either of the two following patterns:

```
Value 2: X Value 1: Y ABC
Value 2: X ABC
```

And I always prefer the `Value 1`. In other words when Value 1 exists I want to grab that value not Value 2.

I have tried doing:

```
(Value 1: (?<Value>.*?) ABC)|(Value 2: (?P<ValueAlt>.*?)) ABC
```

In other words making the first option the `Value 2` yet Regex prefers the first match it finds for the entire regex, pipes or not.

Is there a way to tell Regex which pipe to prefer?

My Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/W038X5/1):

Comment: What language are you implementing this regex in?

Comment: Is Value 2 always ahead of Value 1 in the input strings?

Answer (score 2):

> And I always prefer the Value 1. In other words when Value 1 exists I want to grab that value not Value 2

You can use this atomic group with an alternation:

```
.*\b(?>Value 1: (?<Value1>\w+)|Value 2: (?<Value2>\w+))
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W038X5/5)

---

**EDIT:**

However if `value` tags can be in any order then you can use:

```
(?>.*\bValue 1: (?<Value1>\w+)|\bValue 2: (?<Value2>\w+)).*
```

[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/W038X5/7)

Comment: That's not part of question so I will request OP to clarify.

Comment: @mickmackusa: [Check this demo for your scenario](https://regex101.com/r/W038X5/6)

Comment: @anubhava Value 1 (the one I want) is always second when both Value 1 and Value 2 exist. Sorry if the naming convention confused that fact.

Comment: @anubhava Yes and no. I guess I wasn't specific enough that the pattern in fact has a huge random block of text before hand and right now I'm capturing all of that so I need to tweak it, otherwise as is yes it does.

Comment: Remember answer can solve only described problem in question :) If you had more complex cases written in question then I would have addressed them as well.